# Is it possible to maintain multiple properties files for a single MSBuild scan?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.6

I would like to maintain one generic properties file to, for example, contain the SonarQube login information.
Each specific project would then have its own properties file.
Is there a way to accomplish this?  It seems that only one properties file is recognized.

I am running SonarQube v5.6.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You could create a small program that creates the properties file for you just before scanning.

Comment: The main reason I'd like the flexibility of maintaining a generic properties file is to keep the login separate. The other settings should be applicable to everyone and will be maintained in our version control system (Git).
Generating a properties file at build time is manageable, but, if a mechanism already exists to support multiple properties files, that would be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Scanner for MSBuild documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) :

- you can add login information under the Scanner installation directory (hence common to all projects), @ *scanner_install_dir\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml*
- project specific properties can then be passed via command line when executing the scanner
- for very special cases (rarely needed), you can also [set Additional Analysis Parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Additional+Analysis+Parameters)

Comment: My SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe is installed in the directory C:\SonarQube\Scanners\sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.0.629SonarQube.Analysis.xml

Comment: My SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe is installed in the directory C:\SonarQube\Scanners\sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.0.629 
I modified the SonarQube.Analysis.xml in that directory to contain the login information.  That worked fine until I added /s:C:\Temp\Project.Properties.xml to the command line.
The Project.Properties.xml only contained:
<Property Name="sonar.verbose">true</Property>
But that was enough to cause the scanner to ignore the SonarQube.Analysis.xml file and the login failed.

Comment: @SteveK Use the /d option. See the last line in [Additional Analysis Parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Additional+Analysis+Parameters)

Comment: @JeroenHeier, I was hoping to avoid using the /d option for passing login information because the command line is visible in the build logs.
Since it seems that I am unable to use multiple properties files though, I will probably need to resort to using the /D.
BTW. We have too many properties to try to pass  most of them to SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild via the command line, so the bulk of them need to be in a properties file.